# erro em criar matriz com variáveis em c++

Tags: c++, classes

Quando faço declaração de matrizes em c++ dentro de uma classe, definindo "linhas' e "colunas" dessa matriz por números inteiros diretamente com argumentos, exemplo [2][5] consigo ter o correto funcionamento.

Entretanto quando utilizo variáveis dentro dos argumentos da matriz ele me da um erro de compilação.(dessa forma abaixo)

```
     private:
       int x;
       int y;
       float matriz[x][y];
```

Erro:  invalid use of non-static data member Matriz::x
       invalid use of non-static data member Matriz::y

(esse programa que estou tentando fazer, é basicamente uma matriz para representar conjunto dos números reais).

Comment: Você deve definir um valor fixo para a matriz, infelizmente não tem como colocar uma "variável" sem valor definido entre os colchetes da matriz.

Comment: Utilize o operador new para alocação dinâmica.

Comment: certo, como eu deveria fazer isso?, não tive muita experiência com matriz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como observado em um dos comentários, você pode alocar dinamicamente a memória para o membro matriz. Abaixo um exemplo (obs. eu coloquei uma função para preencher e outra para imprimir a matriz criada. Acho que assim fica mais fácil para entender o exemplo):

```
#include <iostream>

class MatrizDinamica{

private:
   int x;
   int y;   
   //declara a matriz como um ponteiro de ponteiros
   float** matriz;

public:
   MatrizDinamica(int rows, int columns){
      x = rows;
      y = columns;      
      //aloca a memória dinamicamente
      matriz = new float*[x];
      for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
         matriz[i] = new float[y];
      }
   }
   ~MatrizDinamica(){      
      //e não se esqueça de deletar no destructor a memória previamente alocada
     for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
         delete[] matriz[i];
      }
      delete[] matriz;
   }

   void preencherMatriz(){
     int counter = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
         matriz[i][j] = (float) counter;
         counter++;
      }
     }
   }

   void imprimirMatriz(){
   for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < x; j++){
         std::cout << matriz[i][j] << "\t";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
     }
   }
};

int main(){

   int rows, columns;
   std::cin >> rows >> columns;
   MatrizDinamica mMatriz(rows, columns);
   mMatriz.preencherMatriz();
   mMatriz.imprimirMatriz();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: o meu real motivo dessa pergunta é que eu preciso resolver um problema onde o usuário determina o tamanho da matriz, mas o seu código está além do meu nível mas já deu pra ter uma ideia bem clara, muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu conseguiria só fazer declarando a matriz como ponteiro? por que tem que ser ponteiro de ponteiro? // me surgiu essa dúvida agora.

Comment: @Vitor, Ponteiro de ponteiro é o equivalente à matriz de duas dimensões. Se você usasse apenas ponteiro teria apenas uma dimensão. Então, se uma dimensão só for suficiente para o seu projeto, pode usar um único ponteiro. Outro detalhe: você chegou a considerar o uso de std::vector?

Comment: Rapaz eu tava querendo implementar em um exercício de soma de matrizes que o usuário digitasse a quantidade de linhas e colunas, mas acabei fazendo dessa forma da uma olhada. https://notepad.pw/share/ocme0uxa